# Android : How to implement the Subscription Type for in-app product

Tags: java, android, google-play

**One Quick Question....**

As far I know, Google Play does not provide any API Framework for implementing the In-app Product, Supports only through logging in Google Checkout Merchant Account. So, **Is there any way to implement the Subscription type such as Auto-Renewal and User-Renewal as in iPhone because if the user deletes the app from his device, if he reinstalls the app, how to get the Subscription details?**

Please share your views in implementing the in-app Product with Subscription Type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but the new Google Play In-App Subscription Billing framework auto-renews by default, until the user cancels.

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)